# Program a new 2008 corvette key fob

Tags: chevrolet, key, fob, corvette

How to program new key fob with no other key fob available for a 2008 Corvette.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As with most vehicles, you can't. You either have to have another key already coded, or you have to take the car somewhere to have it done (ie: dealership or locksmith). This is actually a security feature built in so Joe Schmoe can't come along and code a new key/fob and steal your car.